# What should the permission for .git folder look like? error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, git, ansible

I cloned repo to reproduce some examples with Ansible
when I go for

```
ansible-playbook install_dependencies.yml
```

I am having error

```
TASK [fetch k3s ansible role from github] ************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "fetch", "--tags", "origin"], "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied\n"}
```

My .git folder

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 ./
drwxrwxr-x 9 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 branches/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki   269 мај  2 07:08 config
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki    73 мај  2 07:08 description
-rwxr-xr-x 1 miki miki    21 мај  2 07:08 HEAD*
drwxrwxr-x 2 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 hooks/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki 18715 мај  2 07:08 index
drwxrwxr-x 2 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 info/
drwxrwxr-x 3 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 logs/
drwxrwxr-x 4 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 objects/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 miki miki   112 мај  2 07:08 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x 5 miki miki  4096 мај  2 07:08 refs/
```

My .ansible folder

```
~/.ansible$ ll
total 24
drwxrwxr-x   6 miki miki 4096 апр 18 14:12 ./
drwxr-x---+ 49 miki miki 4096 мај  3 11:32 ../
-rw-rw-r--   1 miki miki    0 апр 17 17:24 ansible.log
drwxrwxr-x   3 miki miki 4096 апр 18 14:12 collections/
drwx------   2 miki miki 4096 апр 29 10:32 cp/
drwx------   2 miki miki 4096 апр 18 14:12 galaxy_cache/
-rw-------   1 miki miki    0 апр 11 15:53 galaxy_token
drwx------   2 miki miki 4096 мај  3 11:39 tmp/
```

My playbook

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "OS release={{ ansible_distribution_release }}, OS version={{ ansible_distribution_version }}"

    - name: fetch k3s ansible role from github
      delegate_to: localhost
      git:
        repo: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible.git
        clone: true
        dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/../k3s-ansible"
```

with -vvv output

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: miki
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~miki && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/miki/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574="` echo /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/miki/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/modules/git.py
<localhost> PUT /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-122450_cjm4srf/tmpek6go9yg TO /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574/AnsiballZ_git.py
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574/ /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574/AnsiballZ_git.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574/AnsiballZ_git.py && sleep 0'
<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/miki/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1683108974.034215-122617-263104769488574/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": [
        "/usr/bin/git",
        "fetch",
        "--tags",
        "origin"
    ],
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "accept_hostkey": false,
            "accept_newhostkey": false,
            "archive": null,
            "archive_prefix": null,
            "bare": false,
            "clone": true,
            "depth": null,
            "dest": "/home/miki/prac/k3s-cluster-kvm/../k3s-ansible",
            "executable": null,
            "force": false,
            "gpg_whitelist": [],
            "key_file": null,
            "recursive": true,
            "reference": null,
            "refspec": null,
            "remote": "origin",
            "repo": "https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible.git",
            "separate_git_dir": null,
            "single_branch": false,
            "ssh_opts": null,
            "track_submodules": false,
            "umask": null,
            "update": true,
            "verify_commit": false,
            "version": "HEAD"
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to download remote objects and refs:  error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied\n"
```

}

How should I change permissions?

Comment: Permissions look fine if ansible is being run as user miki (you didn't say). Might be a MAC issue (apparmor/selinux) / might be trying to access a different git root.

Comment: @symcbean How to check that?

Comment: I presume you mean whether its a different git root....you'll need to go through the playbook very carefully and see where its trying to download the role to.

Comment: A MAC issue will be reported in your logs (you didn't say which distro you were using either)

Comment: @symcbean Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Check permissions on /home/miki/prac & /home/miki/prac/k3s-ansible & /home/miki/prac/k3s-ansible/.git